# How to move an actor from a point to another with velocity and acceleration

Tags: libgdx

I want an actor to move with velocity (speed) and acceleration to specified coordinate. Yes I know `MoveTo` action can move an actor to the coordinate that we want. But it doesn't move an actor with velocity and acceleration. It just calculates duration so there is no velocity no acceleration if we move actor using `MoveTo` action. How can we set acceleration and velocity for different destination coordinates to move actor ?

For example there can be a class like following but I don't know how it to be

```
class MyActor extends Actor {

    private Vector2 destination;

    public void setVelocity(float velocity) {
         ... codes
         ..
         .
    }

    public void setAcceleration(float acc) {
        ... codes
        ..
        .
    }

    public void move(float delta) {
        ... codes
        ..
        .
    }

    public void setDestination(Vector2 destination) {
        this.destination = destination;
        ... codes
        ..
        .
    }

    public void act(float delta) {
        super.act(delta);
        move(delta);
    }

}

MyActor actor = new MyActor();
actor.setVelocity(5);
actor.setAcceleration(0.2f);
actor.setDestination(new Vector2(250, 300));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can divide distance by velocity to get duration.

You might want to remove existing move actions when adding a new one so they don't start piling up. I put a method for that below. Not sure if you could simplify it by simply removing the action from within the for loop. That could possibly mess up the iterator.

```
class MyActor extends Actor {

    public float velocity = 20f; //arbitrary initial value
    private final Vector2 tmpV = new Vector2(); //for calculations

    public void setDestination (float x, float y){
        clearMoveAction(); // If you want to interrupt any existing motion
        float distance = tmpV.set(x - getX(), y - getY()).len();
        addAction(Actions.moveTo(x, y, distance / velocity));
    }

    void clearMoveAction(){
        Array<Action> actions = getActions();
        Action moveAction = null;
        for (Action action : actions)
            if (action instanceof MoveToAction){
                moveAction = action;
                break;
            }
        if (moveAction != null)
            removeAction(moveAction);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks your answer but I've updated my question. You can review it. If you add acceleration feature to you answer, it's done.

Comment: With existing actions in LibGDX, you can't do this directly. But you can set an interpolation on the MoveToAction like `Interpolation.pow2in` to get a similar effect if you aren't needing the fine control of the exact acceleration. If you do need that control, you can make a custom action, or write in all the code as suggested in your original question. Is that what you need?

Comment: Having an object accelerate toward a point and then stop on a dime tends to look unnatural. It's more common to accelerate at the beginning, and then decelerate. `Interpolation.pow2` or `Interpolation.fade` would be good for that.

Comment: Also, is it possible you might set a new destination when it is still in transit? If so, do you need to start the motion with the same speed you were already going? That would require significantly more complicated math involving a bit of calculus.